# Enviar data desde angular a exprees

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

resulta que estoy intentando enviar una información desde el frontend en angular a un backend en express para guardarla en una Db de mongoDB.
Cuando la envio por medio de POSTMAN el backend se ejecuta correctamente, pero si lo hago desde el navegador no sucede nada... he revisado mucho y no doy con el error..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Frontend:

```
 soliSave(soli){      
    console.log('Solisave', soli)
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/solicitudsemillero", soli)  
            .map((response: Response) =>response.json())              
  }
```

Backend:

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
console.log("POST solicitud Sermillero")
var body = req.body;
console.log(body)
var semillero = new Semillero({ //referencia a una variable de tipo usuario
    Id_Estudiante: body.Id_Estudiante,
    Id_Grupo: body.Id_Grupo,
    Id_Semi: body.Id_Semi,
    Actividad_Semi:body.Actividad_Semi,
    Proyecto_Semi:body.Proyecto_Semi,
    Objetivo_Semi: body.Objetivo_Semi,
    Objetivo_Especifico_Semi:body.Objetivo_Especifico_Semi,
    Justificacion_Semi: body.Justificacion_Semi
}); 

semillero.save((err,solicitudGuardado)=>{
    if(err){
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok:false,
            mensaje: 'Error al enviar solicitud semillero!',
            errors:err
        });          
    }
    res.status(201).json({
        ok:true,
        semillero: solicitudGuardado,
        usuariotoken: req.semillero
    });
});
```

});

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, llevo algunos dias con este error y no he podido.
Psdta: desde el navegador puedo cargar info de la Db sin problemas.

Comment: Por favor añade tu código, en algunos navegadores y para algunas personas con problemas de visión no podrían descifrar esa imagen.

Comment: Sospecho que tienes problema de CORS

Comment: Que erro te aparece en la consola del navegador? como menciona JackNavaRow tal vez tienes un problema de cors, pero seria util mirar el error.

Comment: No me aparece ningun error, simplemente no hace nada, como si nunca usara la ruta ni enviara datos...

Comment: ¿Porqué la ruta en tu backend es `app.post('/', ...)` y en tu frontend apuntas a `/solicitudsemillero`? Aunque en teoría tu ruta del backend captura todo lo que le pidas (mala práctica si no lo corriges). Hace falta más información para saber la causa del problema. Por ejemplo ¿usas algún `parser` para llenar el Objeto `body`? ¿Cómo envías la solicitud desde Postman, y qué diferencias puede haber con la forma en que la envías desde tu front?. Si pudieras dar más detalles sería más fácil ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: por que ya esta mencionadas anteriormente en otro archivo, entonces por eso se pone el '/' en el archivo actual, para indicar que se esta trabajando sobre la ruta base ya mencionada, en este caso '/solicitudsemillero'